Getting AWS Glue Table Compaction to trigger
I am having trouble getting compaction to work on a Glue table.
I have created a Glue database and a Glue table.
I have an S3 bucket setup.
I have enabled table optimization in the Glue dashboard optimization section using an optimization role that was setup as outlined here.
So in order to test that compaction works, my understanding is that I need to add data to the table that will generate over 50 parquet files that are under 128MB and the files all need to be in the same S3 folder.
Note that I am totally new to Athena, Glue and SQL.
Can someone show me what I need to do to have parquet files generated so that compaction will trigger?
Here is what I have attempted so far -
I created a table using this query that I ran in the AWS Athena query editor -
CREATE TABLE msk_ingestion__qa_apps_us.test_compaction ( customer_id INT, name STRING, age INT, dob DATE, email STRING, address STRING, testcol STRING
)
LOCATION 's3://msk-ingestion--qa-apps-us/test_compaction/'
TBLPROPERTIES ( 'table_type' = 'ICEBERG', 'format' = 'parquet'
)

I created this job and ran it successfully, which created over 100 parquet files in the tables bucket named in the fashion of "part-00000-xxxx-xxx-xxx-snappy.parquet" which are all around 2.7K in size.
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DateType
from faker import Faker
import random

# Initialize Glue job context
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 's3_target_bucket', 'database_name', 'table_name'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# Parameters
s3_target_bucket = args['s3_target_bucket']
database_name = args['database_name']
table_name = args['table_name']

# Define schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("customer_id", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("age", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("dob", DateType(), True),
    StructField("email", StringType(), True),
    StructField("address", StringType(), True),
    StructField("testcol", StringType(), True)
])

# Initialize Faker
fake = Faker()

def generate_data(num_records):
    """Generates sample data for testing."""
    return [(random.randint(1, 10000), fake.name(), random.randint(18, 70), fake.date_of_birth(minimum_age=18),
             fake.email(), fake.address(), "test") for _ in range(num_records)]

# Create and write multiple small files to the same S3 directory
num_files = 10  # Number of files you want to create
records_per_file = 100  # Records per file

for _ in range(num_files):
    data = generate_data(records_per_file)
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
    
    df.write.format("parquet") \
        .mode("append") \
        .option("path", f"s3://{s3_target_bucket}/{table_name}/") \
        .save()

job.commit()


Compaction states it is enabled but it never runs. There is no error displayed in the compaction section of the dashboard.
Is something incorrect with the files that are generated or are the format of the files wrong? Is there a different way to generate the files?
I just want to see compaction run so if there is any other solution I would be extremely grateful for it.

For anyone similarly trying to test compaction, This tutorial gave me all the steps needed -
https://devopstar.com/2023/11/18/lets-try-aws-glue-automatic-compaction-for-apache-iceberg/
